# Should ofstream throw exception when folder name is input?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I want to generate file through `ofstream`, here are the codes.

```
void testOfstream(string filename){
    ofstream ofs(filename, ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc | ofstream::binary);

    char body[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

    ofs.write(body, sizeof(body)/sizeof(char));

    ofs.close();
}
```

- If the parameter `filename` is `C:\\MyProject\\CodeTest2010\\CodeTest2010\\test.txt`, the `test.txt` file is created successfully.
- If the parameter `filename` is `C:\\MyProject\\CodeTest2010\\CodeTest2010\\`, or `C:\\MyProject\\CodeTest2010\\CodeTest2010`, nothing is changed in the folder CodeTest2010. I think it should throw exception to warning that the input file name is invalid.

My question is **why it keeps silence instead of throwing exception, when the input file is folder not a filename?**

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/), I do not find any information about the folder name is input into ofstream.

Comment: streams don't throw exceptions by default http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/

Comment: I disagree that an exception should be thrown here. When you open a file you **expect** it to fail if it is a folder rather than a normal file. This is not truly **exceptional** in my opinion. You should **always** check to see if the file opened correctly. If it didn't then you can report an error and return an error flag. I think exceptions should be reserved for the unexpected, difficult to recover from errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IOStreams by default do not throw exceptions. Instead they delegate error indication to a bitmask type representing certain stream errors. The inability to open a file is classified as a recoverable error and therefore it sets `std::ios_base::failtbit` in its stream state. You can enable exceptions by specifying this bit in the parameters of the `exceptions()` method:

```
ofs.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
```

Comment: Edge case: Filebufs are opened in terms of `fopen`. Attempting to open a directory with libc's implementation of `fopen` will not fail in read-only mode (at least not on osx), and none of the error bits are set in the stream. An unrelated exception *is* thrown by the filebuf as soon as any attempt is made to read from the dir however, regardless of whether the stream has enabled exceptions (with libstdc++ at least).

Comment: @user657267 Interesting. Noted. :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you click through to the description of the constructor you'll see that:

> If the file cannot be opened, the stream's failbit flag is set.

The default behaviour of iostreams is precisely this: failed operations do not throw exceptions but can be detected by checking the stream status bits. You can arrange for the stream to throw exceptions on failed operations using the `ios::exceptions` function although this doesn't apply to the constructor (since you have to construct the stream before you can call that function).

Comment: You can call `exceptions()` directly after construction and it will still throw the exception if it can.